# Getting the value of a select button html/js

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to get the user input(value) of this select option button. Everything I look at online dosen't really tell me how to get this button value so I can use it and manipulate it, please help

[image]

Comment: Please include the code itself instead of an image, also be clear on what you expect and what is the issue you are facing

Comment: Could you expand your question? Include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a click event listener for this.

This code snippet demonstrate what you need to do:

```js
// Get Select List
var favAnimal = document.getElementById("favAnimal");

// Add event Listener for any change in the selection
favAnimal.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (favAnimal != undefined && favAnimal.value != "Choose"){
      //Do actions on selected option
      console.log(favAnimal.value)
  }

});
```

```html
<select id="favAnimal">
 
  <option value="Choose">choose</option>
  <option value="Lion">Lion</option>
  <option value="Shark">Shark</option>
  <option value="Eagle">Eagle</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a select with some options

```
<select id="favAnimal">
  <option value="Choose">Choose</option>
  <option value="lion">Lion</option>
  ...
</select>
```

To get the value of the select you do it like this

```
 var favAnimal = document.getElementById("favAnimal");
 console.log(favAnimal.value);
```